# Rodar sh no java

Tags: java, linux, windows, sh

Estou tentando rodar um arquivo no java com o seguinte comando

```
System.out.println("Linux");
String[] env = {"PATH=/bin:/usr/bin/"};

String cmd = System.getProperty( "user.dir" ) + "/config/atualiza.sh";

  try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, env);
  } catch (IOException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(TestandoSO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
```

Porém nada acontece.

Já testei rodando pelo terminal o sh e executa normalmente.

Meu objetivo é chamar outro arquivo jar. Como não consegui pelo Java estou tentando pelo sh

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/15428431/4319922](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15428431/4319922)

Comment: Acho que você deve utilizar a classe  ProcessBuilder https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: Você mandou executar um arquivo `.sh`, que é um shell script, e não um binário executável convencional. Se chamar passando o comando `sh` na frente irá funcionar. Por exemplo: `String cmd = "sh " + System.getProperty( "user.dir" ) + "/config/atualiza.sh"` (no lugar de `sh` pode ser `bash` também, por exemplo). Se não funcionar, tente passar o caminho completo do shell. Por fim, se o objetivo é chamar outro JAR, poderia ter passado `java -jar <nome do jar>`.

Answer (score -1):

Tenta verificar se está dando alguma mensagem ao executar o comando:

```
try
{
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "COMANDO" );

    InputStream is        = p.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader( is );
    BufferedReader br     = new BufferedReader( isr );

    while ( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null )
    {
        sb.append( line + "\n" );
    }

    System.out.println.( sb.toString() );
}

catch( Exception e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```